# value in new column if two values if two columns match two others Matlab

Tags: matlab, join, matrix, matching

So i have two very long matrices. A sample is given below:

First_Matrix:

```
A = [...
1 1 1; 
1 1 2; 
1 1 3;
1 2 1; 
1 2 2; 
1 2 3;
1 3 1; 
1 3 2; 
1 3 3];
```

Second Matrix

```
B = [...
1 1 916;
1 2 653;
1 3 114];
```

And I would like a thirds matrix that would combine the first matrix with the third column of the second matrix, based on the values in the first two column of the 2 matrices matching (being the same).

So Ouput_Matrix:

```
C = [...
1 1 1 916; 
1 1 2 916; 
1 1 3 916; 
1 2 1 653; 
1 2 2 653; 
1 2 3 653;
1 3 1 114; 
1 3 2 114; 
1 3 3 11];
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your approaches? It's easier to come up several first, describe them in your question here so we can tell you which one is better or maybe alternative one is better. In my opinion, two `for` loop will do the job just fine if you are in hurry.

Comment: I assume the last `11` in `C` should be `114`,  correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the second output of [`ismember`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) with the `'rows'` option to get the indices of the matching, from  which you can easily build the result:

```
[~, ind] = ismember(A(:, [1 2]), B(:, [1 2]), 'rows');
C = [A B(ind, 3)];
```

Comment: I think you meant `C = [A B(ind,3)];`. But it's a very elegant solution!

Comment: I somehow overlooked your answer. Sorry, it really works great. Highly elegant and fast. Thanks a lot, both of you!

Answer (score 1):

The for loop isn't pretty and might slow you down if B is very long. But I don't think it's possible to avoid (edit: it seems it is).

```
A = [1 1 1 
1 1 2 
1 1 3
1 2 1 
1 2 2 
1 2 3
1 3 1 
1 3 2 
1 3 3];

B = [1 1 916
1 2 653
1 3 114];

C = [A zeros(size(A,1),1)];

for i = 1:size(B,1)
    C(all(B(i,1:2)==A(:,1:2),2),4) = B(i,3);
end

C =
 1     1     1   916
 1     1     2   916
 1     1     3   916
 1     2     1   653
 1     2     2   653
 1     2     3   653
 1     3     1   114
 1     3     2   114
 1     3     3   114
```

Comment: Why do you think `for` loop isn't pretty?

Comment: BTW, you could you `all(B(idx,1:2)== A(:,1:2),2)` instead as `all` does take additional argument indicating the dimension.

Comment: Maybe i'm a bit hypersensitive about for loops, but i try to avoid them like the plague because they tend to be bottlenecks and can often be avoided using smart matrix indexing. Thx for the tip about `all()`!

Comment: I think in this case it's a simple comparison and you used index correctly so it is the most efficient solution IMO (and pretty, easy to read, too). And of course, it's easy to come up without exerting brain too much.

Comment: I think I am going to go with Imoes' solution, since I am able to understand it and it also applies to non-sorted columns.

Could you however tell me what will be the difference between Imoes and Y.Y Chang's options? It is clear to me that Chang's will result in less calculation time, but how?

Comment: Chang pointed out a small improvement to my original code which i then included. We aren't talking about different solutions, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve what you want without a for loop, but it may not be the most optimal implementation:

```
n = size(B, 1); % number of rows in B
B_(1, :, :) = B'; % convert to 3D matrix to be able to use elementwise comparision
x = squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq, A(:, 1:2), B_(1, 1:2,:)), 2)); % x(i, j) == 1 if row A(i, :) matches B(j, :)
index = x * (1:n)'; % row B(index(i), :) corresponds with row A(i, :)
A(:, 4) = B(index, 3); % add data to A
```

---

An alternative formulation for `x`, without conversion to 3D, is:

```
x = bsxfun(@eq, A(:, 1), B(:,1)') & bsxfun(@eq, A(:, 2), B(:,2)');
```

The disadvantage of this method is that it less extendable to more matching columns.